# Java Lucene как организовать поиск по точному соответствию?

Tags: java, lucene

например у меня есть такой текст:

```
"String content = "book data weaponry is IS iS Is Nato war force ENTREPRENEUR ENTREPRENEUR";"
```

И внутри него я хочу найти шаблон "IS", т.е чтобы при поиске у меня был результат только "IS".

Но загвоздка в том, что при создании поля для этого контента я использую **new StandardAnalyzer()**
Как я понял он выполняет разные функции, но она из них это перевести слова в нижний регистр. И шаблон он тоже переводит в нижний регистр.

---

Получается если я хочу найти "IS", то на деле я ищу "is" в таком индексе:

```
book data weaponry is is is is nato war force entreprenuer entreprenuer
```

И в результате я найду 4 слова, это "is is is is".

---

Какой результат ожидается: есть шаблон "IS", я ищу его в индексе и нахожу не 4 результатных слов, а лишь одно слово, которое наиболее подходит к этому.

---

Подскажите как можно добиться такого результата? Пока что я могу искать слова без учета регистра. Может быть надо что-то другое использовать, напишите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

`Analyzer` используется для двух вещей:

1. при индексации. Он нормализует и преобразовывает данные, в частности, может  для текста `IS` вставить в индекс и `IS` и `is`.
2. при поиске. В этом случае он нормализует и преобразовывает строку поиска перед тем как, собственно, будет делаться поиск.

Если вы используете `StandardAnalyzer` при индексации и при поиске, то у вас происходит преобразование данных и поискового слова в нижний регистр, и поиск получается регистронезависимым. Если нужен поиск текста в том регистре, в котором он был изначально, то нельзя использовать `StandardAnalyzer`.

Нужно создать свои анализаторы. Для индексации, такой, который будет сохранять оригинал и текст в нижнем регистре. Для поиска, такой, который не преобразовывает поисковую строку (можно унаследовать от `StandardAnalyzer` и убрать из него `LowerCaseFilter`). Тогда при индексации в индекс попадет два варианта. При поиске можно будет выбрать анализатор в зависимости от того, нужен ли регистронезависимый поиск.